# Search array? Then get sub values?

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like

```
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [order_product_id] => 91385
                    [order_id] => 5065
                    [nid] => 2140
                    [title] => Gi Treasure
                    [manufacturer] => 
                    [model] => giftcard
                    [qty] => 5
                    [cost] => 0.00000
                    [price] => 25.00000
                    [weight] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [gift_description] => HJello!
                            [gift_email] => dubccom
                            [gift_sender] => Hello
                            [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-25
                            [gift_title] => Thesure
                            [gift_card] => 2130
                            [gift_price] => 25
                            [gift_qty] => 5
                            [gift_name] => Steveek
                            [module] => uc_product
                            [cert_code] => 8-x8mfqXyUYXze
                        )

                    [order_uid] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [order_product_id] => 91386
                    [order_id] => 5065
                    [nid] => 2140
                    [title] => Gift asure 2
                    [manufacturer] => 
                    [model] => giftcard
                    [qty] => 1
                    [cost] => 0.00000
                    [price] => 35.00000
                    [weight] => 0
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [gift_description] => Hello There!
                            [gift_email] => dubcaom
                            [gift_sender] => Hello
                            [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-25
                            [gift_title] => The Holida
                            [gift_card] => 2134
                            [gift_price] => 35
                            [gift_qty] => 1
                            [gift_name] => Steven
                            [module] => uc_product
                            [cert_code] => 9-8xsxgDW9yrMq
                        )

                    [order_uid] => 1
                )

        )
```

And I want to get the data array from array of products where the `order_product_id` (so if it was 91385 I would get

```
[data] => Array
                        (
                            [gift_description] => Hello
                            [gift_email] => dubccom
                            [gift_sender] => Hello
                            [gift_sendDate] => 2011-10-25
                            [gift_title] => Thesure
                            [gift_card] => 2130
                            [gift_price] => 25
                            [gift_qty] => 5
                            [gift_name] => Steveek
                            [module] => uc_product
                            [cert_code] => 8-x8mfqXyUYXze
                        )
```

Any help how I could do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prod_data = false;
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    if ($product->order_product_id == 91385)
    {
        $prod_data = $product->data;
        break;
    }
}
if ($prod_data) {
    // knock yourself out
}
```

Quite similar to plain English, huh?

Answer (score 2):

```
function search_products($id,$products)
{
    $id = intval($id);
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        if($product->order_product_id == $id)
        {
            return($product->data);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

An educated guess at what you're looking for. Call it like `search_products(91385, $products)`. If it returns null, it hasn't found the product ID. I also added a call to `intval` so if you're relying on user input for this, it'll be an int regardless. If you already sanitize it to an int, this doesn't hurt.

EDIT: Misread original post. Updated from array syntax to object property syntax.

Comment: Just FYI, there is no need to call `return null;` as the last line of a function, as this is what happens implicitly.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Hmm, so it does. Regardless, it can't hurt

Answer (score 1):

```
function data_by_order ($arr, $orderId) {
  foreach ($arr as $item) { // Loop the array
    if ($item->order_product_id == $orderId) { // Test this item for the right order id
      return $item->data; // Return the data array
    }
  }
  return FALSE; // Return false if we didn't find it
}

// Example usage:
$data = data_by_order($array,91385);
print_r($data);
```